# How to sync two folders with command line tools?

Tags: linux, files, file-copy, synchronization

Having migrated to Linux from Windows, I would like to find an alternative software to Winmerge or rather learn command line tools to compare and sync two folders on Linux. I would be grateful if you could tell me how to do the following tasks on the command line... (I have studied diff and rsync, but I still need some help.)

We have two folders: "/home/user/A" and "/home/user/B"

Folder A is the place where regular files and folders are saved and folder B is a backup folder that serves as a complete mirror of folder A. (Nothing is directly saved or modified by the user in folder B.)

My questions are:

- How to list files that exist only in folder B? (E.g. the ones deleted from folder A since the last synchronization.)
- How to copy files that exist in only folder B back into folder A?
- How to list files that exist in both folders but have different timestamps or sizes? (The ones that have been modified in folder A since last synronization. I would like to avoid using checksums, because there are tens of thousands of files and it'd make the process too slow.)
- How to make an exact copy of folder A into folder B? I mean, copy everything from folder A into folder B that exists only in folder A and delete everything from folder B that exists only in folder B, but without touching the files that are the same in both folders.

Comment: Why not use a proper backup program for this?  Duplicity is one example.

Comment: I recently published https://alternativeto.net/software/order66/about

Answer (score 241, accepted):

This puts folder A into folder B:

```
rsync -avu --delete "/home/user/A" "/home/user/B"
```

If you want the **contents of folders A and B** to be the same, put `/home/user/A/` (with the slash) as the source. This takes not the folder A but all of its content and puts it into folder B. Like this:

```
rsync -avu --delete "/home/user/A/" "/home/user/B"
```

- `-a` Do the sync preserving all filesystem attributes
- `-v` run verbosely
- `-u` only copy files with a newer modification time (or size difference if the times are equal)
- `--delete` delete the files in target folder that do not exist in the source

Manpage: https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.html

Comment: **rsync**: run rsync app, **-a**: do the sync preserving all filesystem attributes, **-v**: run verbosely, **-z**: compress the data during the sync (transport the data in compressed mode), **--delete**: delete the files in target folder that do not exist in the source, **/home/user/A**: source folder, **/home/user/B**: target folder

Comment: Hi SonicARG, I totally forgot to get back to this and put the explanation, thanks submitting the explanation, I put yours in the answer, hope you don't mind.

Comment: Rsync is primarly meant to copy files between different computers, as explained here it can serve the purpose to sync directories as well.

So the -z option is interesting to reduce network traffic and thus enhance the performance of an rsync between 2 computers: ( read data from disk -> compress) ===network===> (uncompress->write to disk)

Using -z to sync 2 directories on the same host is a bit silly and waste of cpu cycles as you would get (read data from disk -> compress -> uncompress -> write to disk)

Comment: @GerritCap, I made an edit, thanks for your valuable input

Comment: I've tried the command but it create a sub-dir `/home/user/B/A` instead of overwrite A's content to B's content. Could you help me to have a look on it?

Comment: If `-a` (preserve all file attributes) is not needed, e.g. because of copying from a Linux to a Windows file system, you might need the `-r` switch, i.e. pass `rsync -rvu`. Otherwise no sub directories are copied and you will see the unfriendly and confusing error message "skipping directory ."

Comment: Important note in response to Luke's comment regarding trailing slashes - from the manpage:

"A trailing slash on the source changes this behavior to avoid creating an additional directory level at the destination. You can think of a trailing / on a source as meaning "copy the contents of this directory" as opposed to "copy the directory by name", but in both cases the attributes of the containing directory are transferred to the containing directory on the destination." - Bottom line, add a trailing slash to the source if you don't want a subdirectory created on the destination

Comment: 'puts' is probably not the correct phrasing as the source folder is untouched.  Just my $0.02.

Answer (score 18):

You could `unison` tool developed by Benjamin Pierce at U Penn.

Let us assume you have two directories,

`/home/user/Documents/dirA/` and `/home/user/Documents/dirB/`

To synchronize these two, you may use:

~$`unison -ui text /home/user/Documents/dirA/ /home/user/Documents/dirB/`

In output, `unison` will display each and every directory and file that is *different* in the two directories you have asked to sync. It will recommend to additively synchronize (replicate missing file in both locations) on the initial run, then create and maintain a synchronization tree on your machine, and on subsequent runs it will implement true synchronization (i.e., if you delete a file from `.../dirA`, it will get deleted from `.../dirB` as well. You can also compare each and every change and optionally choose to *forward* or *reverse* synchronize between the two directories.

Optionally, to launch graphical interface, simply remove the `-ui text` option from your command, although I find the `cli` simpler and faster to use.

More on this: [Unison tutorial at Unison user documentation](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#tutorial).

Answer (score 16):

The answer from TuxForLife is pretty good, but I strongly suggest you use `-c` when syncing locally. You can argue that it's not worth the time/network penalty to do it for remote syncs, but it is totally worth it for local files because the speed is so great.

> ```
> -c, --checksum
>        This forces the sender to checksum every regular file using a 128-bit  MD4
>        checksum.   It  does this during the initial file-system scan as it builds
>        the list of all available files. The receiver then checksums  its  version
>        of  each  file  (if  it exists and it has the same size as its sender-side
>        counterpart) in order to decide which files need to be updated: files with
>        either  a  changed  size  or a changed checksum are selected for transfer.
>        Since this whole-file checksumming of all files on both sides of the  con-
>        nection  occurs  in  addition to the automatic checksum verifications that
>        occur during a file's transfer, this option can be quite slow.
>
>        Note that rsync always verifies that each transferred file  was  correctly
>        reconstructed  on  the receiving side by checking its whole-file checksum,
>        but that automatic after-the-transfer verification has nothing to do  with
>        this  option's  before-the-transfer  "Does  this file need to be updated?"
>        check.
> ```

This shows how having the same size and time stamps can fail you.

## The setup

```
$ cd /tmp

$ mkdir -p {A,b}/1/2/{3,4}

$ echo "\___________from A" | \
      tee A/1/2/x  | tee A/1/2/3/y  | tee A/1/2/4/z  | \
  tr A b | \
      tee b/1/2/x  | tee b/1/2/3/y  | tee b/1/2/4/z  | \
      tee b/1/2/x0 | tee b/1/2/3/y0 >     b/1/2/4/z0

$ find A b -type f | xargs -I% sh -c "echo %; cat %;"
A/1/2/3/y
\___________from A
A/1/2/4/z
\___________from A
A/1/2/x
\___________from A
b/1/2/3/y
\___________from b
b/1/2/3/y0
\___________from b
b/1/2/4/z
\___________from b
b/1/2/4/z0
\___________from b
b/1/2/x
\___________from b
b/1/2/x0
\___________from b
```

## The rsync that copies nothing because the files all have the same size and timestamp

```
$ rsync -avu A/ b
building file list ... done

sent 138 bytes  received 20 bytes  316.00 bytes/sec
total size is 57  speedup is 0.36

$ find A b -type f | xargs -I% sh -c "echo %; cat %;"
A/1/2/3/y
\___________from A
A/1/2/4/z
\___________from A
A/1/2/x
\___________from A
b/1/2/3/y
\___________from b
b/1/2/3/y0
\___________from b
b/1/2/4/z
\___________from b
b/1/2/4/z0
\___________from b
b/1/2/x
\___________from b
b/1/2/x0
\___________from b
```

## The rsync that works correctly because it compares checksums

```
$ rsync -cavu A/ b
building file list ... done
1/2/x
1/2/3/y
1/2/4/z

sent 381 bytes  received 86 bytes  934.00 bytes/sec
total size is 57  speedup is 0.12

$ find A b -type f | xargs -I% sh -c "echo %; cat %;"
A/1/2/3/y
\___________from A
A/1/2/4/z
\___________from A
A/1/2/x
\___________from A
b/1/2/3/y
\___________from A
b/1/2/3/y0
\___________from b
b/1/2/4/z
\___________from A
b/1/2/4/z0
\___________from b
b/1/2/x
\___________from A
b/1/2/x0
\___________from b
```

Comment: does -c and -u works well together?

Comment: @SergeyKorzhov it does. The `-u' still works as usual to update only if destination is not newer.

Answer (score 7):

This is what I'm using for backing up personal files, where I don't care about everything covered by `-a`, and want more useful information printed.

```bsh
rsync -rtu --delete --info=del,name,stats2 "/home/<user>/<src>/" "/run/media/<user>/<drive>/<dst>"
```

From the [rsync man page](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.html):

> -r, --recursive
> This tells rsync to copy directories recursively.
>
> -t, --times
> This tells rsync to transfer modification times along with the files and update them on the remote system.
>
> -u, --update
> This forces rsync to skip any files which exist on the destination and have a modified time that is newer than the source file. (If an existing destination file has a modification time equal to the source file's, it will be updated if the sizes are different.)
>
> --delete
> This tells rsync to delete extraneous files from the receiving side (ones that aren't on the sending side), but only for the directories that are being synchronized.
>
> --info=FLAGS
> This option lets you have fine-grained control over the information output you want to see.

From `rsync --info=help`

```
DEL        Mention deletions on the receiving side  
NAME       Mention 1) updated file/dir names, 2) unchanged names  
STATS      Mention statistics at end of run (levels 1-3)
```

While less explicit, this is seemingly equivalent and shorter:

```bsh
rsync -rtuv --delete --info=stats2 "/home/<user>/<src>/" "/run/media/<user>/<drive>/<dst>"
```

> -v, --verbose
> A single -v will give you information about what files are being transferred and a brief summary at the end [stats1].

Answer (score 3):

You might have a look at [Fitus/Zaloha.sh](https://github.com/Fitus/Zaloha.sh). It is a synchronizer implemented as a bash shell script that uses only standard Unix commands. It is easy to use:

```
$ Zaloha.sh --sourceDir="test_source" --backupDir="test_backup"
```

Answer (score 1):

Old thread but used this to sync up two 2TB drives.

Using

```
 $ rsync -cavu --delete /home/user/A/* /home/user/B/
```

did not work (says "no such directory exists"), but using

```
 $ rsync -cavu --delete /home/user/A /home/user/B
```

did work...

Answer (score 1):

Another option: https://github.com/mikkorantalainen/rsync-continuous

This script uses `bash`, `inotifywait` and `rsync` over `ssh` to create very fast one-way sync because only modified files need to be transferred and if only part of the file has been modified, rsync will only transfer the modified part.

Comment: A useful option is to provide a way to add rsync options. For example, I need to `--exclude` a huge directory from the source.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it this way:

```
rsync -avu --delete /home/user/A/* /home/user/B/
```

This way you will copy the content of folder A into folder B, not the content of folder A itself.

Comment: https://linux-freebsd.ru/linux/programmnoe_obespechenie-linux/sinhronizatsiya-faylov-s-pomoshhyu-rsync-po-ssh-linux-freebsd/

Comment: this sentence doesnt make sense to me what is the difference between content of folder A and content of folder A itself?