# Can you use symbolic links to always remove one layer of a directory tree?

Tags: symlink

Is it possible to use symbolic links or some other method, i.e. a 'virtual directory' or mount, by which the following is achieved, and persistent?

Directory tree A, original

```
root dir 
|
 +-- dir 1
 |  |  
 |  +-- dir 1.1
```

Directory tree B, symlinked/virtualised to remove one layer in the tree

```
root dir 
|
 +-- dir 1.1
```

I know it can be done as a one time operation by generating symbolic links, but I'm wondering if there's a way to make it persistent, so that if I add a folder 1.2 in directory tree A, it will always show up in the root of directory tree B?

Comment: Hello inthevidual, could you [explain a little more](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/582611/edit) (in your question) what problem you're trying to solve here. There might be solutions using a different approach.

Comment: Please also specify what extent of persistence you desire. For instance, persistent across shifts of file systems, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rsync` with some script that is ran when new item is created in the first directory. something like `rsync --avu delete /dirA /dirB` This is helpful: [How to sync folders](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203846/how-to-sync-two-folders-with-command-line-tools) For the script you can use `inotify` to monitor the create/delete actions in the directory